# Open-Sql translated to native oracle sql chooses arbitrary indices by where clause?

Tags: indexing, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause, abap

We spotted a strange behaviour during a customer project. The underlying database is oracle, so this question is flagged for as oracle, because we only operate at the open-sql-layer, and this makes our knowledge of the underlying database-architecture/processes/optimizations equal to zero.

**Let me describe the design as it is:**

1. We have two tables , one is the core-table, the other is the 
   optional additional table
2. The core table is always populated, the other table not
3. The core table has the keys MANDT, WERKS and our own running ID
4. The optional table has the same keys, which are set up as a set
    of foreing keys, referring to the core-table
5. The foreign-key-setup is: Control desired, no message, kind of foreign keys is "not specified", no cardinality is set.

**Let me now specify, what we do/want to do:**

1. We have an own query builder, which allows us to create select-statements almost by a drag and drop technique.
2. We want to select the core table with an inner join to the optional table ( yes, in this specific case master-data tells us, that this optional table is always populated, too), based on the three keyfields(two actually).
3. We have some indices on both tables, in the core we use the indexed ERDAT( creation date ) and in the optional table we use an an char20-field, also indexed.
4. We want to select excactly this way.
5. We debug...

**Let me describe, what we saw:**

1. We analyzed the created select statement in the debugger, and verified, that
   it looked, as we want it to be, meaning, the where clause first covers ERDAT from the core table and the second line covers the char20-field of the optional table
2. We made runtime analyzis (providing other values for the where-criteria), running ST05 etc... though the underlying database being a black-box to us, apparently ST05 could show the generated native SQL-index-order, which was used.
3. The result: The index CHAR20 of the optional table is used first, and the index on ERDAT of thecore table is used as second.

**Let me ask:**

1. Can anybody explain, why ? (if more information is necessary, I will try to provide them ).

Answer (score 3):

Oracle will most commonly use a cost-based optimizer to execute the query. Depending on how selective the index is and how the join is performed best, the DB decides which table to query first.

I can only guess, but I think your core table has a lot of values and the index on that table is not very selective. So querying the core table first might produce many result rows.
If the optional table only has few rows, it is expected to deliver less rows when queried using the index on the CHAR20 field. In this case, the DB will start with a smaller result set into the join, and hence prefer this option.

The query optimization is a very complex process, you can read more about this here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/optimops.htm

Comment: In our case the master data demands for the processing, that, whenever the core table is populated, so the optional table also will be populated, so we will have all the time the same amount of records inside both tables. But, what I can imagine, is (and I have not read the link yet), is, that a field of character 20 and a date-field having 8 only  digits, which are even more limitied to days/months has a much bigger likelyhood to carry unique values than the date. Might be, that the db optimizes in ways like this,
Can we use hints in this case to force own index-order-usage ?

Comment: Yes, you can use hints in Open SQL. See SAP Note 129385 (Database hints in Open SQL): http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/129385